# How to Save .svg in Illustrator so it shows right on Adroid?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, android, optimization

I am trying to create a `.svg` image for Android devices, but it is not visible clearly in the device. How should I save the file from Adobe Illustrator and how can I optimise the file?

Comment: svg's appear fine on my android device/s

Comment: When I save a file as SVG in Illustrator with standard settings it shows fine on android for me.

Comment: The last few versions of Illustrator export improperly formatted svg when using the "Export for screen option". Use "save as" The reason for this is that the useless, greedy individuals at Adobe are incapable of doing anything properly.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes converted SVG don't work fine and it may show some distortions, that's because the SVG file is not perfectly designed to demonstrate curve drawn with bezier curve method or what we call it paths. of course Illustrator is perfect in that. You may see an orthographicaly drawing presented well but when it comes to curves it will distort.

My solution is to divide your curves in sub curves and don't simplify the path.

Go to `Objects>path>Add Anchor Points` and do it whatever it takes. two or three times.

Answer (score 0):

I usually save SVG right on the border of the graphics. In Web Desktop Browsers you definatelly need some css usually to scale things. But i would go with the screen size i want the svg to initially appear.

Screenshots might help.